# iFrame and IE 11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

Want to include the nice Rotated Gallery from "simbyone.com" in my website with an iFrame. 
Works with all browsers but not with IE11! Text appears but Java Script fails. However a direct call to the URL: 
"http://simbyone.com/demo/how-to-create-a-rotated-gallery/"
 works in all browsers. Any ideas why IE11 does not run it in an iframe.  The code for the gallery can easely be downloaded at "simbyone.com". This is my HTML code which proves the problem with IE11:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11"/>
 <title>Rotated Gallery</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <b>Hello World</b>
 <p><iframe align="middle" frameborder="0" height="500" scrolling="no"
      src="http://simbyone.com/demo/how-to-create-a-rotated-gallery/" 
      width="800"></iframe></p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: is iframe on same domain as page? Any errors or warnings in dev tools console? Is all page html valid?

Comment: No - see html-code below:

Comment: don't drop code into comment blocks...update the question where it can be formatted and read...then delete thos comments

Comment: Also clarify what `No` means... hard to anser 2 questions with one word

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line to your HTML:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11"/>`

Answer (score 0):

With IE dev-tool found that a call to a function in jQuery returning "access denied". After installation of the newest jQuery Lib - IE11 worked like charm.